# Exchange Polish Zloty to Malaysian Ringgit (MYR) in Malaysia?

Tags: exchange, malaysia

I got 3,000 Polish Zloty that I can't change to Malaysian Ringgit. Does anyone know where I can change them? I am Malaysian.

[image]

Comment: Where? In Poland or Malaysia?

Comment: In Malaysia.. Most money changer not accept it.

Comment: The money you posted on the picture is pretty much worthless, it was deprecated in 1994... and even then it would be worth only price of a small snack. Where did you get it?

Comment: @Kuba that's an answer !

Comment: Even if it were not deprecated... usually you can not exchange arbitrary currency in arbitrary countries, at least not routinely... you need to exchange out of the 1st county's currency *while still in that country* into a world currency.  For example, while still in Poland, buy Euros, pounds or dollars with the zloty.  Then take the world currency (e.g. Euros) to Malaysia to buy Ringgit.  You will lose out some due to exchanging twice but it's really the only way.

Answer (score 24):

You won't be able to exchange this money, it's deprecated since 1995. Then PLN was introduced (standing for PoLish New) with value 1 new zloty = 10 000 old zlotys. Even before denomination the money you have would be worth nothing, around 7 euro cents. If you bought this you've been scammed, I'm sorry.

This is how 100 PLN note looks like now, worth around 24 €
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Im speechless.. 

Comment: This is a good reason to know what the current money of various countries looks like. It's also helpful to know what countries have redenominated or demonetized old currency and which still recognize older versions. A lot of people know that USA currency never expires (even WW2-era USD is still good), but this rule does not apply to most other countries.